# Error in converting argument from 'const_Ty' to const custom struct

Tags: c++11

I have a custom comparator and I pass in two const references of a custom struct to be compared, however, I get the following error:

> 'bool cmp::operator()(const LogObjects &, const LogObjects &)' cannot convert argument 2 from 'const_Ty' to 'const LogObjects &'.

I've tried adding and removing const, and references but it didn't work.

```
bool cmp::operator()(const LogObjects &a, const LogObjects &b) { // body }

struct LogObjects {
    string category;
    string message;
    string timestamp;
    long long int time;
    int entry_id;

sort(master.begin(), master.end(), cmp());
auto it1 = lower_bound(master.begin(), master.end(), time, cmp());
auto it2 = upper_bound(master.begin(), master.end(), time, cmp());

};
```

(master is a vector of LogObjects and time is a long long int)

Comment: can you add the part of code that's using the comparator?

Comment: without that part the only thing I can think of is that you should change your cmp::operator() to be a const member

Comment: From the error message, my guess would be that you are trying to use `cmp` to compare objects of some type that is not in fact `LogObjects`

Comment: The code you've shown [compiles](https://rextester.com/DICTGH17358). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code you haven't shown. Prepare a [mcve]

Comment: "time is a long long int"  << this is why you are getting the error. It's in lower_bound, upper_bound. 

the functions try to compare item in your vector( of type LogObject)  with time (of type long long).


Easiest way to fix would be to create LogObject timeObj and pass that to lower/upperBound. (If cmp depends on time only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so the question can be closed, answering here as well.

> time is a long long int

Is why you are getting the error. 
lower_bound and upper_bound try to compare item in your vector( of type LogObject) with time (of type long long). Easiest way to fix would be to create LogObject timeObj and pass that to lower/upperBound. (If cmp depends on time only)

something like this:

```
LogObjects timeObject;
timeObject.time = time;
auto it1 = lower_bound(master.begin(), master.end(), timeObject, cmp());
auto it2 = upper_bound(master.begin(), master.end(), timeObject, cmp());
```